# Android - Tracer for OpenGL ES throws "Broken pipe"

Tags: android, opengl-es

I cannot get the trace from Tracer for OpenGL ES.

Every time I try to enable the two options:

`Collect Framebuffer contents on eglSwapBuffers()`

And

`Collect Framebuffer contents on glDraw()`

I get the error: **Error while setting trace options: Broken pipe**

Someone can help me to solve this? I'd really like to get this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this error on my Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2. By downgrading the Galaxy Nexus to stock 4.1.2, I was able to get this to work. I've opened a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53426

Comment: Oh... in fact I made my tests with a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2
Thanks for clarify this is a bug.